# how to require local file like node module

Tags: javascript, node-modules, package.json

`./config.js` is my local file.
I can require it like this `var config = require('./config.js');`

How can I require it like this `var config = require('config');`

Thank you very much!

Comment: Require will assume your files are `.js` so it's optional to include the extension. You will still need to provide the path though if it's a local file and not a node package.